# Angular: Sending the value of object using replaysubject

Tags: angular, angular8, behaviorsubject

I have a add button, on which I am executing

```
onAddProduct(productname,price){
    this.purchasedProduct.push(productname);
    this.totalAmount += price;
    this.matBadgeNumber++;
    this.orderInfo=new OrderInfo(this.matBadgeNumber,this.purchasedProduct,this.totalAmount);
    this.tooltip = "you have "+ this.matBadgeNumber+ " products in cart";
  }
```

then I clicked on buy button which executes

```
buyNow(){
    this.http.orderDetailEmitter.next(this.orderInfo);
  }
```

OrderInfo

```
export class OrderInfo {

  matBadgeNumber: number;
  purchasedProduct: String[];
  totalAmount : Number;

  constructor(matBadgeNumber: number, purchasedProduct: String[],totalAmount : Number ) {
      this.matBadgeNumber = matBadgeNumber;
      this.purchasedProduct = purchasedProduct;
      this.totalAmount = totalAmount;
  }
}
```

HttpClientService

```
readonly orderDetailEmitter = new ReplaySubject<OrderInfo>(1);
```

OrderDetailsComponent

```
export class OrderDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  products;
  orderDetails;

  constructor(private http : HttpClientService) {

    this.orderDetails=this.http.orderDetailEmitter;
    console.log("this.orderDetails"+this.orderDetails);
    this.products = Object.values(this.orderDetails);
    console.log("this.products"+this.products);


   }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

}
```

but while i am printing the value of orderDetails it is giving me Object [object], after using Oject.values(this.orderDetails), it is giving me some strange values

```
false,,false,false,false,,,,true,1,Infinity,nextInfiniteTimeWindow(value) {
        const _events = this._events;
        _events.push(value);
        if (_events.length > this._bufferSize) {
            _events.shift();
        }
        super.next(value);
    }
```

all I need is to get the changed value of orderInfo object via replaysubject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http.orderDetailEmitter` is an observable. You need to subscribe to it to obtain the values. Also seeing the `OrderInfo` class, I think you meant to assign the list of products (`purchasedProduct` property) to variable `this.products` instead of `Object.values(this.orderDetails)`. Try the following

```js
constructor(private http : HttpClientService) {
  this.http.orderDetailEmitter.subscribe(
    details => {
      this.orderDetails = details;
      console.log("this.orderDetails"+this.orderDetails);
      this.products = this.orderDetails.purchasedProduct;
      console.log("this.products"+this.products);
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: yes, this are working, I think previously I was using only single value, in that case it was not required to subscribe it